# Calculate the Min and Max of specific columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I wanted to calculate the Min and Max among in a data frame for a specific columns using pipe function and I am not getting the right values. The range here is the last 5 weeks, so min and max of last 5 weeks.

The output I am getting is wrong. Can someone help me out or let me know what I did wrong.

```
#       Material Calendar Year/Week 2023/39  ...  2023/40 2023/41 2023/42 2023/43 2023/44 2023/45
# 1 XAB-01-02-03               Deal      85  ...       60      51      65      74      12       1
# 2 XAB-01-02-03             Profit      18  ...       38      61      94      65      20      65
# 3 XAB-01-02-03          Comission      32  ...       32      42      49      77      53      58
# 4 XAB-01-02-03 Project Commission       8  ...        7      93      41       3      89      50
# 5 XAB-03-05-10               Deal      86  ...       96      41      11       2      32      88
# 6 XAB-03-05-10             Profit      16  ...      100      26       1      11      50      82
# 7 XAB-03-05-10          Comission      32  ...       92      34      97      19      93      47
# 8 XAB-03-05-10 Project Commission      27  ...       46      12      23      96      14      22
```

The code I wrote is given below:

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

Book7 <- read_excel("X:/X/X/X- X/X/Book7.xlsx",
                    sheet = "Sheet12")

First_Date <- head(tail(colnames(Book7)),1) 
Last_Date <- tail(colnames(Book7),1)

Book7 <- Book7 %>% 
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date)))) %>% 
  mutate(Max = max(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date)))) %>% 
  mutate(Min = min(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date))))
```

The wrong Output which I got is given below:

```
#       Material Calendar Year/Week   ...  2023/42 2023/43 2023/44 2023/45 Sum Max Min
# 1 XAB-01-02-03               Deal   ...       65      74      12       1 263 100   1
# 2 XAB-01-02-03             Profit   ...       94      65      20      65 343 100   1
# 3 XAB-01-02-03          Comission   ...       49      77      53      58 311 100   1
# 4 XAB-01-02-03 Project Commission   ...       41       3      89      50 283 100   1
# 5 XAB-03-05-10               Deal   ...       11       2      32      88 270 100   1
# 6 XAB-03-05-10             Profit   ...        1      11      50      82 270 100   1
# 7 XAB-03-05-10          Comission   ...       97      19      93      47 382 100   1
# 8 XAB-03-05-10 Project Commission   ...       23      96      14      22 213 100   1
```

For Clarity, add `dput`.

```
structure(list(Material = c("XAB-01-02-03", "XAB-01-02-03", "XAB-01-02-03", 
"XAB-01-02-03", "XAB-03-05-10", "XAB-03-05-10", "XAB-03-05-10", 
"XAB-03-05-10"), `Calendar Year/Week` = c("Deal", "Profit", "Comission", 
"Project Commission", "Deal", "Profit", "Comission", "Project Commission"
), `2023/28` = c(6, 4, 40, 21, 18, 37, 65, 61), `2023/29` = c(92, 
92, 98, 33, 54, 43, 5, 51), `2023/30` = c(81, 56, 77, 54, 56, 
53, 21, 92), `2023/31` = c(5, 0, 28, 81, 88, 67, 94, 58), `2023/32` = c(54, 
41, 91, 10, 47, 67, 40, 17), `2023/33` = c(82, 73, 70, 67, 45, 
88, 79, 25), `2023/34` = c(30, 40, 12, 65, 97, 92, 64, 31), `2023/35` = c(46, 
1, 17, 36, 61, 75, 78, 10), `2023/36` = c(4, 43, 88, 100, 65, 
15, 82, 88), `2023/37` = c(83, 73, 17, 96, 53, 9, 94, 10), `2023/38` = c(78, 
75, 44, 30, 89, 51, 45, 30), `2023/39` = c(85, 18, 32, 8, 86, 
16, 32, 27), `2023/40` = c(60, 38, 32, 7, 96, 100, 92, 46), `2023/41` = c(51, 
61, 42, 93, 41, 26, 34, 12), `2023/42` = c(65, 94, 49, 41, 11, 
1, 97, 23), `2023/43` = c(74, 65, 77, 3, 2, 11, 19, 96), `2023/44` = c(12, 
20, 53, 89, 32, 50, 93, 14), `2023/45` = c(1, 65, 58, 50, 88, 
82, 47, 22)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

The output expected is:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output? You are using `pick`, which will return one minimum and one maximum value from all of the columns supplied to it. Perhaps that isn't what you want to do?

Comment: I'm surmising that you want `pmax`/`pmin` rather than `max`/`min` - in which case you change your code to `Max = do.call(pmax, pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date)))` etc.  Note also that `mutate()` takes multiple expressions so you can calculate all your variables in a single call - you don't need to call it for each calculation.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento This worked. Thank you. If you can put this as answer, I could mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what our friend mention in the comment section, we can easily do this, if we use the `do.call` function along with pmax and pmin.

Please try this out, I think this should work for you.

```
Book7 <- Book7 %>% 
  mutate(Sum = rowSums(pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date)))) %>% 
  mutate(Max = do.call(pmax,pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date)))) %>% 
  mutate(Min = do.call(pmin,pick(any_of(First_Date):any_of(Last_Date))))
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
Book7  %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -c(Material, `Calendar Year/Week`), names_to = "Week", values_to = "Value") %>%
    group_by(Material, `Calendar Year/Week`) %>%
    summarise(Sum = sum(Value), Min = min(Value), Max = max(Value), Mean = mean(Value))
```

And another way:

```
Book7  %>% 
    mutate(Sum = rowSums(across(-c(Material, `Calendar Year/Week`))),
           Min = min(across(-c(Material, `Calendar Year/Week`))), 
           Max = max(across(-c(Material, `Calendar Year/Week`))))
```

Update: To get the sum, min, and max over the past 5 rows/weeks (assuming those are the same thing for this), we can use `rollapply` from the `zoo` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

Book7 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Material, `Calendar Year/Week`), names_to = "Week", values_to = "Value") %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(str_extract(Week, "\\d+")), 
         Week = as.numeric(str_extract(Week, "\\d+$"))) %>%
  mutate(Mean = rollmean(Value, 5, fill = NA, align = "right"), 
         Min = rollapply(Value, 5, min, fill = NA, align = "right"),
         Max = rollmax(Value, 5, fill = NA, align = "right"), .by= c(Material, `Calendar Year/Week`))
```

Comment: I want the min and max of a range, which is the last 5 weeks. This would give me min and max function of the whole data right. So that is not the expectation. Can you please change it such that we get the min and max of the last 5 weeks and I want to specify the column names for the 5 week to set up the range.

Comment: ah okay, I seem to have misunderstood your question. Give me a moment

Comment: Note that `rollmeanr`, `rollapplyr` and `rollmaxr` (all with an r ont he end) can be used in place of `align="right"`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to calculate summaries for specific columns.

At first, you should hard code the column names, or think of a more robust way that doesn't depend on column orders than ranges of column names. After specific operations, column order can change faster than you think.

```
fcol <- c("2023/40", "2023/41", "2023/42", "2023/43", "2023/44", "2023/45")
```

Then use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` for row-wise operations (`MARGIN=2` would be column-wise).

```
sapply(list(Sum=sum, Min=min, Max=max), \(f) apply(Book7[fcol], MARGIN=1, f))
#      Sum Min Max
# [1,] 263   1  74
# [2,] 343  20  94
# [3,] 311  32  77
# [4,] 283   3  93
# [5,] 270   2  96
# [6,] 270   1 100
# [7,] 382  19  97
# [8,] 213  12  96
```

However, `row*` functions from the *matrixStats* package are much faster.

```
library(matrixStats)
sapply(c(Sum=rowSums2, Min=rowMins, Max=rowMaxs), \(f) f(as.matrix(Book7[fcol])))
#      Sum Min Max
# [1,] 263   1  74
# [2,] 343  20  94
# [3,] 311  32  77
# [4,] 283   3  93
# [5,] 270   2  96
# [6,] 270   1 100
# [7,] 382  19  97
# [8,] 213  12  96
```

Use `?cbind` to add columns to you data frame.

---

*Data:*

```
Book7 <- structure(list(Material = c("XAB-01-02-03", "XAB-01-02-03", "XAB-01-02-03", 
"XAB-01-02-03", "XAB-03-05-10", "XAB-03-05-10", "XAB-03-05-10", 
"XAB-03-05-10"), `Calendar Year/Week` = c("Deal", "Profit", "Comission", 
"Project Commission", "Deal", "Profit", "Comission", "Project Commission"
), `2023/28` = c(6, 4, 40, 21, 18, 37, 65, 61), `2023/29` = c(92, 
92, 98, 33, 54, 43, 5, 51), `2023/30` = c(81, 56, 77, 54, 56, 
53, 21, 92), `2023/31` = c(5, 0, 28, 81, 88, 67, 94, 58), `2023/32` = c(54, 
41, 91, 10, 47, 67, 40, 17), `2023/33` = c(82, 73, 70, 67, 45, 
88, 79, 25), `2023/34` = c(30, 40, 12, 65, 97, 92, 64, 31), `2023/35` = c(46, 
1, 17, 36, 61, 75, 78, 10), `2023/36` = c(4, 43, 88, 100, 65, 
15, 82, 88), `2023/37` = c(83, 73, 17, 96, 53, 9, 94, 10), `2023/38` = c(78, 
75, 44, 30, 89, 51, 45, 30), `2023/39` = c(85, 18, 32, 8, 86, 
16, 32, 27), `2023/40` = c(60, 38, 32, 7, 96, 100, 92, 46), `2023/41` = c(51, 
61, 42, 93, 41, 26, 34, 12), `2023/42` = c(65, 94, 49, 41, 11, 
1, 97, 23), `2023/43` = c(74, 65, 77, 3, 2, 11, 19, 96), `2023/44` = c(12, 
20, 53, 89, 32, 50, 93, 14), `2023/45` = c(1, 65, 58, 50, 88, 
82, 47, 22)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: I want to pipe the function and I cant hard code the dates as it would change in the situation, depending upon various condition. So I have to pick the column names and use it for the range. 
Can you please update it such that I can specify the column names.

Comment: this is quite neat! I haven't had reason to use the matrixStats package before, but maybe I should 